# Object manipulation

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, object, data-manipulation

I am using either PHP or Javascript to manipulate an json object from API sample:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "label": "employeeCount",
        "stats": [
            {
                "year": "2015",
                "value": "10"
            },
            {
                "year": "2017",
                "value": "30"
            },
            {
                "year": "2016",
                "value": "50"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "label": "managerCount",
        "stats": [
            {
                "year": "2015",
                "value": "2"
            },
            {
                "year": "2017",
                "value": "4"
            },
            {
                "year": "2016",
                "value": "6"
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to categorize it by the year as object like such:

```
"record": {
  "2015" : {
    "employeeCount": "10",
    "managerCount": "2"
  },
  "2016" : {
    "employeeCount": "30",
    "managerCount": "4"
  },
  "2017"{
    "employeeCount": "50",
    "managerCount": "6"
  }
}
```

The number of `year` and the number of `label` will be different from the API call so I am thinking about using a for loop to make it happen.  But so far no success.  What approach would you use for this kind of manipulation?

Comment: How about deserializing the json object, manipulating it and converting to json string again.

Comment: "But so far no success" what have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

**LOGIC** - Idea is to iterate over `data array` in object and then for each entry in data array, iterate over its corresponding `stats array` to populate the object based on `year`. While iterating over the `stat array`, **check for existing entry in resultant object**. If does not exist, create an entry for it. Update the entry by adding the `label` as **key** and `value` from its corresponding object in `stat array`.

```js
let obj = {"data":[{"label":"employeeCount","stats":[{"year":"2015","value":"10"},{"year":"2017","value":"30"},{"year":"2016","value":"50"}]},{"label":"managerCount","stats":[{"year":"2015","value":"2"},{"year":"2017","value":"4"},{"year":"2016","value":"6"}]}]};

// Create the response object
let r = {"record":{}};
// Iterate over data array
obj.data.forEach(o => {
  // Iterate over stats for each object in data array
  o.stats.forEach(s => {
    // Create entry for year in result object if it does not exist
    r.record[s.year] = r.record[s.year] || {};
    // Add the label of data array object with corresponding stat value in resultant object
    r.record[s.year][o.label] = s.value;
  });
});
console.log(r);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard - Point taken. Updated answer

Answer (score 0):

```
let data = json.data
let map={}
for(let i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    let stats = data[i].stats
    for(let j=0;j<stats.length;j++){
        let it = stats[j]
        if(!map[it.year]){
            map[it.year]={}
        }
        map[it.year][data[i].label]=it.value
    }
}
console.log({record:map})
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.